# Getting smugmug unique photo key after upload using phpSmug

Tags: php, api

I am uploading an image to smugmug using phpSmug, the code works, but I am not getting any response. I need to some how get the unique key smugmug assigned to the photo after uploading it.  This is the working code I am using:

```
require_once( "phpSmug.php" );

try {
$f = new phpSmug( "APIKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AppName=xxxxxxxxxxxx" );
// Login With EmailAddress and Password
$f->login( "EmailAddress=xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Password=xxxxx" );   
$f->images_upload("AlbumID=xxxxxxxx", "File=TestImage.jpg");


}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "{$e->getMessage()} (Error Code: {$e->getCode()})";
}
```

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/lildude/phpSmug/blob/master/phpSmug.php#L593), `images_upload` returns an array with information, or false.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Instead of doing:

```
$f->images_upload("AlbumID=xxxxxxxx", "File=TestImage.jpg");
```

The response is returned, so I can just this this instead:

```
$response = $f->images_upload("AlbumID=xxxxxxxx", "File=TestImage.jpg");
echo "ID: $response[id]<BR>Key: $response[Key]<BR>URL: $response[URL]";
```

Then I am given an array back with the id, key, and url

I hope this helps someone else.